# List of lists into two separate lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like the following:

```
l = [[[2.04356, 0.799842], 0.940545], [[0.600883, 0.363704], -0.104026], [[-0.150264, -0.0907573], -0.756651]]
```

I now want to split this list into two lists:

```
X = [[2.04356, 0.799842],[0.600883, 0.363704],[-0.150264, -0.0907573]]
y = [[0.940545],[-0.104026],[-0.756651]]
```

I thought either

```
my_list2, my_list1 = zip(*l)
```

or

```
my_list1 = [i[0] for i in l]
my_list2 = [i[1] for i in l]
```

would work but they don't give me the desired output.

Comment: `my_list2 = [i[0] for i in l]` - you have written 0 instead of 1

Comment: If you want the second one to output each element in a list for `y`, then you need to do `my_list2 = [[i[1]] for i in l]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `my_list1` is ok, but second should read `i[1]` and wrap in a list `[i[1]]` to get your output

```
x_list = [i[0] for i in l]
y_list = [[i[1]] for i in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `numpy`.

```
# create a nested list
my_list = [[[2.04356, 0.799842], 0.940545], [[0.600883, 0.363704], -0.104026], [[-0.150264, -0.0907573], -0.756651]]

# convert to numpy array
import numpy as np
arr_l = np.array(my_list)

my_list1 = arr_l[:, 0]
my_list2 = arr_l[:, 1]
```

This can be useful when your list goes very big.